# Xhr обновляет страницу

Tags: javascript, ajax, xhr

Посылаю форму через файл send.php, всё отлично, но страница всё равно обновляется, то есть открывается по ссылке файл http://mysite/send.php.

При успешной отправке данных должен выводиться попап, но он тоже не появляется

```js
"use strict";

(function() {
  // Скрипт для формы обратной связи
  var FORM_HANDLER_URL = 'php/send.php';
  var feedbackBlock = document.querySelector('.contact-us');


  if (feedbackBlock) {
    var feedbackForm = feedbackBlock.querySelector('.contact-us__form');

    var XHR_RESPONSE_TO_STATUS = {
      1: 'success',
      2: 'error',
      0: 'validation error',
    }

    // Обработка события Submit - срабатывает только при условии валидности основных полей
    window.onSubmit = function(xhr) {
      // Определяем ответ сервера
      var xhrResponseText = xhr.responseText;

      // Задаем функцию показа попапа
      var showPopup = function(serverResponseText) {
        // Находим в разметке всплывающее окно
        var popup = feedbackBlock.querySelector('.contact-us__sent-wrapper');

        var status = XHR_RESPONSE_TO_STATUS[serverResponseText];
        if (status === 'success') {
          popup.classList.add('contact-us__sent-wrapper--open');
        }
      }

      // Задаем поведение в зависимости от ответа сервера
      switch (xhrResponseText) {
        case "1":
        case "2":
          showPopup(xhrResponseText);
          break;
        case "0":
          showError(captchaBlock);
          captchaBlock.addEventListener('input', function() {
            removeError(captchaBlock);
          });
      }
    };

    // Глобальный метод при ошибке отправки
    window.onErrorSubmit = function() {
      alert('Ошибка соединения. Попробуйте еще раз');
    };

    // Обработчик события submit
    var onFormSubmit = function(evt) {
      // Отменяем отправку формы по умолчанию
      // evt.preventDefault();
      // Собираем данные с формы
      var data = new FormData(feedbackForm);
      // Создаем xhr запрос
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.responseType = '';

      // Валидация полей:
      var fields = feedbackForm.querySelectorAll('input');

      // Задаем валидность по умолчанию = true
      var validity = true;

      // Валидируем поля формы
      fields.forEach(function(field) {
        var fieldName = field.name;
        if (!field.validity.valid) {
          validity = false;
          evt.preventDefault();
          var fieldLabel = document.querySelector("[for=" + fieldName + "-field]");
          showError(field, fieldLabel);
          field.addEventListener('input', function() {
            if (field.validity.valid) {
              validity = true;
              removeError(field);
            }
          });
        }
      });

      if (validity) {

        xhr.open('POST', FORM_HANDLER_URL);
        xhr.send(data);
      }
    }

    feedbackForm.addEventListener('submit', onFormSubmit);
  };
})();
```

```css
.contact-us__sent-wrapper {
  display: none;
}

.contact-us__sent-wrapper--open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section class="contact-us">
  <h2 class="contact-us__title">Свяжитесь с нами</h2>
  <p class="contact-us__description">Наши менеджеры перезвонят Вам в скором времени</p>
  <div class="contact-us__wrapper">
    <form class="contact-us__form" action="../php/send.php" method="POST">
      <fieldset class="contact-us__fieldset">
        <legend class="visually-hidden">Данные</legend>
        <ul class="contact-us__list">
          <li class="contact-us__item">
            <input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-zА-Яа-яЁё]{2,20}" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя*" required>
          </li>
          <li class="contact-us__item">
            <input id="phone" minlength="7" maxlength="20" pattern="((\+7)|8)?[\-\s]?\(?[0-9]{3}\)?[\-\s]?[0-9]{3}[\-\s]?[0-9]{2}[\-\s]?[0-9]{2}" type="tel" name="tel" placeholder="Контактный телефон*" required>
          </li>
          <li class="contact-us__item">
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email*" required>
          </li>
          <li class="contact-us__item">
            <textarea id="comment-field" placeholder="Комментарий" cols="20" rows="3" name="message"></textarea>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </fieldset>
  </div>
  <div class="submit__wrapper">
    <p class="submit__text">Нажимая на кнопку «Отправить запрос»,<br>вы&nbsp;принимаете условия обработки
    </p>
    <a class="submit__link" href="">персональных данных</a>
    <button class="submit__button" type="submit">
            <span>Отправить запрос</span>
        </button>
  </div>
  </form>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="contact-us__sent-wrapper">
  <h2 class="contact-us__title contact-us__sent">Заявка отправлена</h2>
  <p class="contact-us__description">Мы получили вашу заявку, в ближайшее время наш менеджер свяжется с вами.</p>
  <div class="contact-us__wrapper">
    <form class="contact-us-sent__form" action="" method="">
      <fieldset class="contact-us__fieldset">
        <legend class="visually-hidden">Данные</legend>
        <ul class="contact-us__list">
          <li class="contact-us__item">
            <input type="text" minlength="2" pattern="[- A-zА-я]+" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя*" required>
            <label class="vusually-hidden" for="name">Имя</label>
          </li>
          <li class="contact-us__item">
            <input id="phone-field" type="tel" minlength="7" maxlength="20" pattern="((\+7)|8)?[\-\s]?\(?[0-9]{3}\)?[\-\s]?[0-9]{3}[\-\s]?[0-9]{2}[\-\s]?[0-9]{2}" name="tel" placeholder="Контактный телефон*" required>
            <label class="vusually-hidden" for="tel">Телефон</label>
          </li>
          <li class="contact-us__item">
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email*" required>
            <label class="vusually-hidden" for="email">Почта</label>
          </li>
          <li class="contact-us__item">
            <textarea placeholder="Комментарий" cols="20" rows="3" name="message"></textarea>
            <label class="vusually-hidden" for="message">Комментарий</label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </fieldset>
  </div>
  <div class="submit__wrapper">
    <p class="submit__text">Нажимая на кнопку «Отправить запрос»,<br>вы&nbsp;принимаете условия обработки
    </p>
    <a class="submit__link" href="">персональных данных</a>
    <button class="submit__button" type="submit">
            <span>Отправить запрос</span>
        </button>
  </div>
  </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: `evt.preventDefault();` раскомментируйте

Comment: @InDevX теперь работает, но отсылает данные 2 раза

Answer (score 0, accepted):

внутри тела функции `onFormSubmit` добавьте в самом начале строку `evt.preventDefautl();`.
примерно так:

```
var onFormSubmit = function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefautl();
    // ... код функции
```

Comment: UPD: теперь работает, но отсылает данные два раза и попап не выводится